# Const in javascript is getting redefined

Tags: javascript, constants

I recently faced a major issue because of `const` getting redefined. Not sure if it's by design. It will be a great help if anyone can explain me this.

```js
'use strict'

const b = 61;
const nm = true;
if(nm){
    const b = 82;
    console.log(b);

}
```